# Concatenating Substition variables with strings

Tags: sql, sqlplus, oracle12c

I am modyfying a SQLplus script that creates a user, connects to the user and creates tables and puts values in those tables. This script had a set username and password for user like the below

```
CONNECT store/store_password@test
```

However I want to replace store_password with a variable v_store_password which I have put at the start:

```
ACCEPT v_store_password CHAR PROMPT 'Please type in store password: ' HIDE
```

Basically what I tried was this:

```
CONNECT store/&v_store_password || @test;
```

The above unfortunately does not work. I read some where that a "." can be used but it doesn't work.

How to concatenate or add to Substition variables?

Also how to add numbers to these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/*make a file called file.connection.txt and enter username#password#tnsname#*/
/* write below code into batch file*/
CLS
ECHO 
TITLE Database test script (ORACLE)
@echo off
cls
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=#" %%a in (file_connection.txt) do (
sqlplus -l "%%a/%%b@%%c " @test.sql
)

exit

Answer (score 0):

I actually dicovered that I have not included the & in front of variable like below

```
CREATE USER store IDENTIFIED BY v_store_password;
```

and the "." is varables concatenation character which ends them so the solution is:

```
CONNECT store/&v_store_password.@test;
```